# Nested Sets with rational numbers on Redis

Tags: database-design, redis

I'm tried to implement a nested set DB model on Redis with rational number how is described in this paper http://arxiv.org/abs/0806.3115

But, after two weeks of study, I'm stuck with design... here my schema

**Nested Sets Model**

```
 **Add Nodes**(name, is_root= nil, namespace=nil){

   $id = INCR namespace:nodes:counter *//generate unique id for every node*

  HSET namespace:nodes:by_id = field:$id value: {Json object with numerator and denominator   of node and next sibling}

   HSET namespace:nodes:by_name field:hash($node name) value:$id *// For search with node name*

*// the score is obtained with numerator/denominator, the set contains all item ids of a category*

Create an entry on ZSET namespace:nodes_list   



   if is_root{

*//for performance purpose instead of calculate the root nodes with filter on ZSET, store all here*

   Insert id into SET named: namespace:root_nodes:ids  
}}

   **Get whole Node Tree** {

   For each id stored on namespace:root_nodes:ids($id){

   GET namespace:nodes:$Id values nv dv snv sdv

   *//stuck here*

  }

  }
```

Is Possible with my design to get the whole tree in decent speed? Hints?

Maybe another data structure is better but doesn't know any, you?

Have categories like amazon with items that are present in multiples categories, if an item is present on child cat, the parent cat contains also the item.

Comment: +1 Interesting question (Might be better suited on programmers.stackexchange ? ). Have you considered contacting Dan Hazel about it?

Comment: Have posted on redis group after this question: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/redis-db/L_MB7xr1bPA and have find a solution, but maybe on SO find another.